# Laravel 4 redirect loop issue after session expired

Tags: laravel-4, session-cookies, server-configuration, redirect-loop

I have created an app with Laravel 4.2 and it's working well on localhost and also had no issue on my old server.
I got new dedicated server and I had transferred to the new server.
In the new server I got a really bad issue, which is my app goes to redirect loop after session has been expired and it's happening while I'm navigating on pages or leaving browser for while.
I should remove the domain cookies by chrome extension to access my app again and login to the dashboard.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, I tried a lot of thing to fix the issue but my app still in redirect loop.
Finally I figured out what was the issue. 
The problem was for installation of my WHM, So I had reformatted my server SSD and installed WHM carefully from beginning and selected all the option that I needed.
When it's done, I had installed my app and everything was working very well.